# MAIL DBCC CHECKDB RESULTS

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-mail, dbcc-checkdb

I want to regularly run DBCC CHECKDB on my production database. My database is real-time and DBCC CHECKDB is very expensive query, that`s why I want to write a maintenance plan to execute the query on nights when the activity is low. I want to set the query results to be sent as mail in order to check it when I am able. My question is, how can I set the query results to be sent to my e-mail when it is executed ?

Comment: Which SQL Server version , you are using?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2012, Standard Edition

Comment: Use Ola Hallengren's scripts and schedule a job for checkdb. Set option to log results to table (create standalone database for storing scripts and logs if possible) and configure mail alerts if needed. Seems (in my opinion) as more elegant solution. https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-integrity-check.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there may be other ways of doing this, but at my shop, I run DBCC CHECKDB via SQLCMD bat files and use the -o parameter to route the output to a flat text file.  Then, in the same bat file, I use SQLCMD to invoke

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
```

and attach the results of the DBCC

This process could be scheduled via either Windows Task Scheduler or you could create a Sql Agent job to run 'Operating System (CMDEXEC) to invoke the SQLCMD.

If you wanted to loop through each online database and run CHECKDB, you could create a utility stored procedure like this with the DBCC options that you want to use. This example skips TEMPDB, but I run a separate automated task for that database alone due to frequent timeouts.

It prints the database name, start time and end time.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[DBCC_CheckAllDatabases]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(max);
    DECLARE @databaseList as CURSOR;
    DECLARE @databaseName as NVARCHAR(500);
    DECLARE @tsql AS NVARCHAR(500);

    SET @databaseList = CURSOR  LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY 
    FOR
          SELECT QUOTENAME([name])
          FROM sys.databases
          WHERE [state] = 0 and [name]<>'tempdb';
    OPEN @databaseList;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @databaseList into @databaseName;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
       SET @Message = 'Starting DBCC for ' + @databaseName + ' -> (' + convert(varchar,getdate(),121) + ')'
       RAISERROR(@Message,0,1) WITH NOWAIT
       SET @tsql = N'DBCC CheckDB(' + @databaseName + ') WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS,NO_INFOMSGS,PHYSICAL_ONLY;';
       RAISERROR(@tsql,0,1) WITH NOWAIT
       EXECUTE (@tsql);
       SET @Message = 'Completed DBCC for ' + @databaseName + ' -> (' + convert(varchar,getdate(),121) + ')'
       RAISERROR(@Message,0,1) WITH NOWAIT

       FETCH NEXT FROM @databaseList into @databaseName;
    END
    CLOSE @databaseList;
    DEALLOCATE @databaseList;
END
```

You could also utilize Aaron Bertrand's [InEachDB](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/) process, if you don't like my example for looping through the databases.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But I need something different, because the query should be run at night time, when I am not at work. It will be perfect if it is possible to write some maintenance plan which can enable to send results of the query or write to txt file as you mentioned automatically once it is executed.

Comment: Windows Scheduled Task could be used to invoke the bat file at the desired time at night.  That's what we do in my shop.